# Why does some Ransomware encrypt also the file header and trailer?

Tags: encryption, file-encryption, ransomware, entropy, file-system

Some time ago I read an article that mentioned that it is possible for some ransomware to change the magic numbers of a file (that makes sense). However, the authors claimed that their method was better, because they calculated the entropy value of the file header and used that to distinguish between encrypted and benign files. However, the magic numbers are, as far as I know, part of the file header (so if they claim that ransomware can change the magic numbers, then it can also change the file header, right? So, why is this not a potential problem in their study?

In another study, this was mentioned:

> However, since the header portion is only 8 bytes in size, the reliability of the data is not high. An intelligent ransomware can bypass the detection technique by not changing the 8-byte pattern.

They also state:

> The trailer format section can most clearly distinguish between the normal encryption formats and ransomware-infected formats. The entropy value of 164 bytes of ASCII code was analyzed. The highest value of the entropy value of the normal file trailer format is lower than the smallest value of the trailer format entropy value of the ransomware infected file.

But in this case I wonder why the ransomware encrypts both the header and the trailer? I mean... it makes more sense to leave it intact (then the malicious software will not be detected), since it only contains metadata (the user cannot recover the file based on that metadata, so why would you encrypt it)?

Comment: *"Some time ago I read an article ..."* - please provide a link to the article so we get more context than you currently provide in your question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yeah, you're right, this is the right link: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00500-018-3257-z.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...why the ransomware encrypts both the header and the trailer?...

Why not? What advantage would it have to not encrypting header and trailer vs. simply encrypting everything - like ransomware traditionally does. Specifically singling out header and footer only makes it more complex. Note that some newer ransomware encrypt only some parts to speed up encryption and/or confuse detection heuristics - but this does also not specifically spare headers and footers.

If there would be a significant disadvantage of encrypting header and footer, like some important security product detecting the malware based on this feature, then ransomware would surely adapt to avoid such detection. There is no technical reason which would make encrypting header and footer unavoidable.

Comment: Thank you Steffen for your response. "Why not?" 
Because in that case defence mechanisms that analyse the header/trailer of a file cannot detect malicious behaviour... Perhaps I should rephrase my question. What if a ransomware author knew I was using header/trailer analysis (to detect encryption)? Would he then choose not to encrypt the header/trailer (to remain undetected), or is that not an option for some reason?

Comment: @Moooz: that would be a significantly different question and thus should be asked as a new one. Don't make your question a moving target, especially if answers already exist.

Comment: "especially if answers already exist"

I couldn't find them, and I read a lot of papers, so if you know where to find the answers, please let me know.

Comment: @Moooz: You might noticed that I've answered your original question. Even if you did not accept the answer - it is still an answer and changing the question would not be the expected action since the answer would no longer fit the question. But to answer *"Would he then choose not to encrypt the header/trailer (to remain undetected), or is that not an option for some reason?"* - attackers adapt and there is no significant technical obstacle to encrypt header and footer - it is just simpler to encrypt everything.

Comment: Well, you have answered my question with "Why not?" Congratulations, what a brilliant answer. It's easier to encrypt the whole file, than just the body.. yeah no shit... Anyway, thanks for your "help". You asked for the link, did you read the paper? No, obviously not, because in such a case your response would be much better than such a general, meaningless answer.

Comment: @Moooz: *" did you read the paper"* - yes I did. And I found nothing in it which assumes that ransomware is taking extra effort to specifically encrypt header and footer. As I said, it simply encrypts everything. *"It's easier to encrypt the whole file, than just the body.. yeah no shit... "* - sorry that such a simple answer does not match your expectation of a more complex reason. That does not make it any less true though.

Comment: @Moooz: *".... Because in that case defence mechanisms that analyse the header/trailer of a file cannot detect malicious behaviour... "* - the paper is not focusing on analyzing header and footer because it is an unavoidable property of ransomware, but because it is a useful feature to detect current ransomware (i.e. coincindental correlation, not causation). If some major security product would actually  rely on this behavior then ransomware would adapt to avoid detection this way, like it does to avoid detection by other heuristics. I've changed my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: Okay, that's fair, thanks. Quite unfortunate, because if I develop such a system (detection based on analysis of file header/trailer), then the RW authors will simply exclude the H/T from encryption to avoid detection (so this method isn't future-proof). In the paper the authors mention that there are currently types of RW that do not encrypt the header, for that reason the authors analyse the trailer instead (but a new sample can also exclude the trailer, to avoid detection) :(

Comment: @Moooz: Unfortunately such AI/ML/heuristics based approaches to detect ransomware, malware, spam etc  often rely on features (like the entropy in specific areas in this case) which are just artifacts of how the currently existing samples work, but which are not actually  required for their functionality. This makes it easy for attackers to evade detection by making small adjustments.  It's like trying to detect criminals by looking for red cars just because they happen to use red cars for a while - but the color is actually irrelevant and can be changed to avoid detection.